# Changes done in mysql backend database not getting reflected neither on frontend website nor inside the server

Tags: nginx, mysql, k3s

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45920596/update-made-in-mysql-database-does-not-reflect-on-the-webpage
I've curled inside the server itself and still the updated data was not received.

I've:

- cleared the cache as per the instructions provided by the application developer.
- reload nginx as we're using nginx as a web server
- checked the db connection.
- commited the changes.
- Haven't restarted the k3s pods that are serving static content.
- I am the host of this application and have cleared cache of redis from the host as well.

Comment: PHPMyAdmin uses the same statements (like SELECT) as any other mysql client. If changes to the DB are not visible on a output, either a different database is used or the statement is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting the pod fixed the issue. Bad, very bad development of software.